# check if nested list is empty

Tags: python, list

My values arrays shows like this

```
values = [array(0., dtype=float32), array(0., dtype=float32)]
```

How to check if the array is empty?

I tried following, but it does not work

```
if not any(values):
    print("Empty list!")
```

Comment: what, exactly, is your criteria for "empty". Please *be precise*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If the values are 0 as in example it should print Empty list.

Comment: what is meant by the values are 0?

Comment: @Kerrim 0 means only 0 appears in the list of list. see the example

Comment: so, `[np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0])]` would be empty??

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga every array will have single 0

Comment: Then `not any(values)` *should* work. However, if the arrays can be non-scalar, it will throw an error... is *that* the issue you are encountering?

Comment: not any(values) did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to search for arrays containing exactly one zero and then print 'empty' we can do the following:

If it should return 'empty' if both are empty you can do that:

```
if not any([bool(value) if len(value) == 1 else True for value in values]):
    print('empty')
```

If it should return 'empty' if one of the nested lists is empty:

```
if not all([bool(value) if len(value) == 1 else True for value in values]):
    print('empty')
```